# Search by value of dict in array

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large list of dicts, each dict has a token.

```
large_list = [{"token": "4kj13", "value1": 10, "value2": 20},
              {"token": "hm9gm", "value1": 15, "value2": 30}]
```

I need to quickly find a dictionary by token, something like

```
print(large_list["4kj13"]["value1"])
```

Is there any elegant way to do it? I think I can create a dictionary token to index:

```
token2index = {"4kj13": 0, "hm9gm": 1}
```

But if there's a better solution, then I would be glad to know.
I can't change the input format (json), though I can create some intermediate data.

UPD: also the content of the dict is not simple, so the list can't be easily transformed to a table
UPD2: tokens are unique

Comment: Are the `token` unique?

Comment: @d.b yes, it is

Comment: What is your output desired from `token2index = {"4kj13": 0, "hm9gm": 1}`? You are proposing to look up the index of a list entry but looking at the values of the dicts in that list?

Comment: @dawg It's just a intermediate result to facilitate the search. I have a token, I find the index of the dict with this token, and then simply use the index to get the right dict in the array

Comment: I think you have the right idea with creating an index dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `list` of `dict` to `dict`

```
d = {x["token"]: x for x in large_list}
d["4kj13"]["value1"]
# 10
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of a specific dict, you can use `next` with an enumerator:

```
def get_token(token):
    try:
        return next(i for i,di in enumerate(large_list) if di['token']==token)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError

>>> large_list[get_token("4kj13")]
{'token': '4kj13', 'value1': 10, 'value2': 20}

>>> large_list[get_token("4kj13")]['value1']
10
```

If the specific token is not found, it raises a `ValueError` in the same manner as [list.index](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
>>> large_list[get_token("4kj1")]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in get_token
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in get_token
ValueError
```

Or you can use `next` with a default value if that is simpler:

```
>>> next((i for i,di in enumerate(large_list) if di['token']=="hm9gm"),-1)
1
>>> next((i for i,di in enumerate(large_list) if di['token']=="hm"),-1)
-1
```